# X-Frame-Options error

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, google-api

I have been using the google+ sign-in API,

1. When the user links his new account(By means of not yet signed in
   Google+ social network) in my created api app
2. The user is directed to create a Google+ profile screen.
3. When submit button is pressed, it was directed to a URL then it doesnt load anymore leaving the screen blank not knowing if the
   user's account was created in google+.

I have traced the error containing this:

`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?XXXXXXXX does not permit cross-origin framing.`

Thus it does not continue to the url because the `X-Frame-Options` is blocking it.

I researched about the X-Frame-Options, saying that it should be set in the header.

How am I going to set it in this header:

```
<meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="{{=response.CLIENT_ID}}" />
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
<meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity" />
<meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />
```

And I am rendering my button this way:

```
(function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script');
   po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
 })();
 function render() {

   // Additional params including the callback, the rest of the params will
   // come from the page-level configuration.
   var additionalParams = {
     'callback': signinCallback,
     'immediate': false,

   };
   // Attach a click listener to a button to trigger the flow.
   var signinButton = document.getElementById('signinButton');
   signinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams); // Will use page level configuration
   });
 }
```

Or what are the other ways to set it? Or how can this be the error be fixed? My backend part is python.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, but I found out what was happening on my end.

I am working on creating a application that runs on Google App Engine in Golang. I took the snippet of code that is necessary to setup the button for the Google+ signin button, and pasted it into my template. The code looked like this, taken straight from the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button#step_4_add_a_google_sign-in_button_to_your_page):

```
        <span
           class="g-signin"
           data-callback="signinCallback"
           data-clientid="CLIENT_ID"
           data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
           data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
           data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login">
```

I did not replace my real clientId with CLIENT_ID, and that was the problem. I replaced the string "CLIENT_ID" with my Google App Engine CLIENT_ID, and it fixed the issue for me. I observed this by watching the Network request/response information on the network tab using Chrome Developer Tools, and observed this odd request with was using CLIENT_ID, which just looked wrong.

Upon further inspection of the code, that was indeed my problem.

Hope this helps!